# Direct Edit Confirmation in GEF EditParts

Tags: java, eclipse, editor, eclipse-gef, draw2d

**Introduction:**
I write an Eclipse plugin containing an editor which I implement with [GEF](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/).
I have nodes and edges in my editor.
The nodes have names and I want to edit the name of the nodes via direct edit.

I install the direct edit policy to the node edit parts:

```
installEditPolicy(EditPolicy.DIRECT_EDIT_ROLE, new NodeNameDirectEditPolicy());
```

and the direct edit policy implements the direct edit command.

**The problem is:**
To confirm the direct edit I have to press STRG + ENTER. If I only press ENTER the direct edit is expanded to a new line. Is there any way to make it possible that the direct edit can be confirmed simply with ENTER? multiline node names are not needed.

Comment: Can you share the code of `NodeNameDirectEditPolicy`? In my implementation `Enter` confirms the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve it by extending the `TextCellEditor(Composite parent, int style)` constructor in your own extension of `TextCellEditor`.

Then, when calling `createCellEditorOn(Composite composite)` in your `DirectEditManager` extension class, let it return `new YOURTextCellEditor(composite, SWT.SINGLE)`.

Verbosely:

*Your own implementation of `TextCellEditor`'s constructor*

```
public YOURTextCellEditor(Composite parent, int style) {
  super(parent, style);
}
```

*`createCellEditorOn(Composite composite)` in your implementation of DirectEditManager`*

```
@Override
protected CellEditor createCellEditorOn(Composite composite) {
    return new YOURTextCellEditor(composite, SWT.SINGLE);
}
```

Perhaps check if you return a new instance of `YOURTextCellEditor` with `SWT.MULTI` or `SWT.MULTI|SWT.WRAP` or similar, this makes your text cell editor's SWT control a multi-line text widget (cf. [SWT Widgets overview](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/widgets/)).

Comment: thx :) SWT.MULTI has hide deep in the system and caused the problem. Fixed bug with the use of SWT.Single